# How do I find what keys mysql will use for a query?

Tags: mysql, index, locking, explain

I just had a query encounter a deadlock, where the lock it was trying to acquire was for an index. But when I used `explain` to visualize the query, I saw that a *different* index was listed under key and possible_key. Going back to the query, I found that the key causing the deadlock was on a column only used in the order by clause, and nowhere else in the query.

This set me thinking: Given an arbitrary SQL statement, how do I find out **all** of the indexes mysql is going to need to acquire a lock on in order for it to run?

Comment: Potentially, any index on any of the tables involved.

Comment: use explain your_query to find out the explain plan for your statement and you will get an idea which index will be used

Comment: @NawazSohail nope - the index listed in the explain query is NOT the index being locked

Comment: try using table maintenance operation optimize/alter to update it's stats as it might not be updated causing the above behavior.

Answer (score 0):

You are approaching this from the wrong direction.  Any query can deadlock anytime.  So, you must be prepared to replay the entire transaction when a deadlock occurs.

Sure, it is a good idea to try to avoid deadlocks, there there are several things that can decrease their frequency.  The main technique is to make queries faster.

In the case you have mentioned, the Optimizer probably decided that avoiding the 'sort' for the `ORDER BY` was better than using any other index, or even using no index.  Let's see `SHOW CREATE TABLE` and `EXPLAIN SELECT` to further dissect what happened.

Another technique is to include the optimal index -- often a "composite" index over multiple columns.  Sometimes it is even good to have a "covering" index -- one that includes all the columns mentioned in the query.

When using `IN`, another technique is to sort the values.